# Что такое указатели?

Tags: c++, указатели

Где лучше прочесть, что такое указатели в C++, а то читаю и ничего непонятно?

Comment: Прочитайте [поиск](http://hashcode.ru/search/?q=%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8&t=question)

Answer (score 10):

**Например** по адресу 0x00000001 лежит переменная типа int со значением 5:

```
//0x00000001    5
int* var = new int;
*var = 5;
delete var;
```

так вот var равен 0x00000001,
а *var равен 5

- ***** это оператор разыменовывания (т.е. *var - значит взять значение по адресу хранящимуся в переменной var)
- *&*   это оператор взятия адреса (не путать со ссылками)

В предыдущем примере от [[@Sever](/users/6593/sever)](/users/6593/sever), было бы нагляднее (имхо) написать так

```
int a=10;   //например адрес а = 0x00000001
int с=15;   //например адрес с = 0x00000002
int *b;     //тут b объявленный указатель
b = &a;     //a == 10, &a == 0x00000001, и теперь b == 0x00000001, *b == 10
b = &с;     //b == 0x00000002, *b == 15
```

### Ссылки

Тут совсем все просто, при объявлении переменной пишется & и потом уже адрес изменить не получится

```
int a = 10;
int &b = a;
//a и b две одинаковые переменные (с тем же значением) 
//и если изменить одну, соответственно во второй будет тоже измененное значение

a == 10;
b == 10;
a = 15;
b == 15;
b = 0;
a == 0;
```

### Пример с функцией

```
void MultipliedByTwice(int* var) {
    *var = (*var) * 2;
}

int main () {
    int num = 32;
    MultipliedByTwice(&num);
    //тут num == 64
    return 0;
}
```

То есть можно сказать что указатели это переменные хранящие в себе адрес.
Если вы собираетесь в функции изменить адрес хранящийся в указателе вам нужно 
иметь *туже* переменную что и передавали в функцию, т.е. ссылку на нее:

```
void ResizeString(char*& resbuffer, long NewSize) {
    char* newbuffer = new char[NewSize+1];
    strcpy_s(newbuffer, NewSize, resbuffer);
    delete[] resbuffer; 
    resbuffer = newbuffer;
}

int main () {
    char* str = new char [4];
    strcpy(str, "Hi!");
    printf(str);
    ResizeString(str, 12);      //str == "Hi!\0????????"
    strcat(str, " And by.");        //str == "Hi! And by.\0"
    printf(str);
    delete str;
    return 0;
}
```

Смысл в том что когда ты передаешь что то в функцию, у функции объявляются свои копии переменных которые ты передал,
т.е. например:

```
int a=10;    //например адрес а = 0x00000001
int *b;  //адрес b например равен 0x00000002, т.е. &b == 0x00000002
b = &a;  //a == 10, &a == 0x00000001, b == 0x00000001, и &b == 0x00000002
*b = 15  //*b == 15 && a == 15 && b == 0x00000001 && &b == 0x00000002

MultipliedByTwice(b);

void MultipliedByTwice(int* var) {  
    //а вот тут уже var == 0x00000001, но &var равен (например) 0x00000003
    *var = (*var) * 2;
}
```

### Масивы указателей

Так как указатели это переменные, то и арефметические аперации к ним тоже применимы:

```
char stackstr[] = "My first string!";
char* strptr = &stackstr[0];    //создаем указатель на первый элемент массива
printf(strptr);                 //выведет "My first string!"
strptr++;
printf(strptr);                 //выведет "y first string!"
strptr += 8;
printf(strptr);                 //выведет "string!"
strptr = strptr - 6;
printf(strptr);                 //выведет "first string!"
```

Тоесть *например* адрес первого элемента массива 0x00000001, тогда соответственно второго 0x00000002, третьего 0x00000003 и т.д.
Указатель это переменная содежащая в себе адрес, (который можно изменить) и в последнем случае наглядно видно что у каждого символа массива есть свой адрес, и что указатель на масив просто хранит в себе адрес который указывает на значение типа char (я к тому что если разименовать указатель "printf( *strptr );" будет выведен символ хранящийся по адресу, а не вся оставшеяся строка

#### Пример от [[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp)

```
void substr(const char* src, int start, int count, char* destBuffer) {
//Тут наглядно видно что именно Создался указатель src из stackstr, и destBuffer из buffer
    if (start > 0) src += start;
    if (count > 0) 
        while(count--) 
            *destBuffer++ = *src++;

    *destBuffer = 0;
}

int main() 
{
    char stackstr[] = "My first string!";
    char buffer[6];

    //из stackstr начиная с 3 символа скопировать 5 символов в buffer
    substr(stackstr, 3, 5, buffer); 
    printf(buffer);         //выведет "first"

    return 0;
}
```

p.s. Не знаю понятно или не понятно, но ко мне тоже это не с первого раза пришло.

Comment: @lirik90, что это за ерунда с substr ? 

Зачем в цикле двигать src ? Зачем какие-то лишние счетчики ?

    if (start > 0) src += start;
    if (count > 0) 
        while(count--) 
            *destBuffer++ = *src++;
    

IMHO как-то так.

Comment: Да, что то я и вправду... не выспавшийся ;) Спасибо!

Comment: А я вспомнил, у меня там просто проверка на конец str была:

     for (int i = 0; i < start; i++, pos++) 
 if (*src++ == 0) return;

Но в любом случае лучше так:

    while(start--)
 if (*src++ == 0) return;

Answer (score 2):

Все переменные хранятся в памяти. А указатель представляет собой **адрес** памяти, который указывает (или ссылается) на определенный участок.

Например:

```
int a=10;
int *b=&a;   //в "b" записали адрес переменной "a"
```

Comment: > Все переменные хранятся в памяти

Не все. Переменная-счетчик, например, в результате оптимизации может стать регистровой.

Comment: Говорим об общем случае. Вот тут подробнее есть. http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Адресация_памяти

Comment: @Sever, я и говорю, что при регистровой адресации нельзя определить указатель на операнд, т.к. у регистра нет адреса. http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Адресация_памяти#Регистровая_адресация

Comment: Я не отрицаю сказанное вами. Но может не стоит заходить так далеко, если человек, пока хочет разобраться и понять что такое указатели.

Comment: @insolor, написать 

    register int i, *p = &i; 

можно. gcc выдаст warning, но сделает .exe. 

Только вот i положит в стек и перед действиями с указателем будет заносить регист в память.

Comment: Каюсь, иногда я излишне придирчив:)

@avp, в данном случае переменная просто перестает быть регистровой.

@sever,

> Говорим об общем случае.

В общем случае переменная может находиться в памяти **или** в регистре ("переменные хранятся в памяти" - это как раз частный случай). Вот в общем-то и все что я хотел сказать. Хотя регистры конечно же тоже память, только не адресуемая, а именуемая.