# Как в структуре через указатель обратиться к конкретному элементу массива?

Tags: c, массивы, указатели, память, структуры

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct Book1 {
    char author[40]; 
    char title[80]; 
    int year; 
    int pages; 
};

int main()
{
    struct Book1 b[10] = {"Gogol","Ganz Küchelgarten",1823,228},c[10];
    memcpy(&c[4],&b[0], sizeof(Book1));
    strcpy(c[4].author, "Eto Gogol");
    c[4].pages = 180;
    struct Book1 *p;
    p = c; //Вот тут вопрос : этот указатель p на что указывает? только на нулевой элемент структурного массива ? А как сделать так, чтобы указатель указывая на начало массива ,потом мог быть использован для указания на 4 элемент
    strcpy(p->author, "unomartina");
    p->pages = 33;
    printf("%d", p->pages);


    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Я имею в виду , что чтобы работать конкретно с 4 ячейкой массива , я мог сделать такое

```
p = &c[4];
```

и потом все изменения бы проходили именно с выбранной ячейкой.Но как сделать так, чтобы написав указатель вот так `p = c` всё равно иметь доступ изменять этими действиями  `strcpy(p->author, "unomartina");`   `p->pages = 33;` четвертую или какую-либо другую нужную ячейку.То есть что нужно добавить в `strcpy(p->author, "unomartina");` и `p->pages = 33;`  ?

Answer (score 1):

Все очень просто. С `p` нужно работать также, как и с `c`:

```
c[4].pages = 180;

struct Book1 *p = c;

printf("%d\n", p[4].pages); // -> 180
printf("%d\n", c[4].pages); // -> 180

p[4].pages = 33;

printf("%d\n", p[4].pages); // -> 33
printf("%d\n", c[4].pages); // -> 33
```

Смотрите, что происходит.

1. `c` эквивалентно `&c[0]`.
2. Значит, когда мы пишем `p = c`, мы говорим, что теперь `p` будет указывать на первый элемент массива.
3. Значит, если нам нужно обратиться к другим элементам массива, нам нужно *сдвинуть* этот указатель, чтобы он указывал на *нужный нам* элемент. Т.е. `p + i` — это адрес i-ного элемента массива.
4. Значит, если, например, нам нужно вывести `pages` из 4-го элемента массива, мы должны написать `(struct Book1*)(p+4)->pages`, что эквивалентно `p[4]->pages` (см. *ISO/IEC 9899:201x 6.5.2.1 Array subscripting*).

---

Для дальнейшего чтения:

1. [Указатели и массивы](http://cpp.com.ru/kr_cbook/ch5kr.html);
2. [Что такое указатели (StackOverflow)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/125270/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8);
3. [Взятие адреса у массива (StackOverflow)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/625641/%D0%92%D0%B7%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0-%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0);
4. [Синтаксический сахар — Массивы C](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80#%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B_%D0%B2_%D0%A1%D0%B8).

Answer (score 0):

Указателю `p`, Вы присвоили адрес начала массива `c`:

```
p = c;
```

Чтобы изменять четвертый элемент через указатель:

```
p = &c[3];
```

A `c[4]` -- это обращение к пятому элементу массива, а не к четвёртому.

Comment: *Я имею в виду , что чтобы работать конкретно с 4 ячейкой массива , я мог сделать такое `p = &c[4];`*. У Вас написано то же самое. Поставил минус.

Answer (score 0):

`p = c + i;` эквивалентно `p = &c[i];` - вас это интересует?